# Distance between exponential and first degree polynomial function

Tags: functions, exponential-function

Consider the functions
$$
\begin{split}
f(x) &= x^{2x}\\
g(x) &= 10x+2
\end{split}
$$

they are defined on the interval $0 \le x \le 1.5$

I'm trying to find the maximum vertical distance between both functions, obviously within the intervals they are defined for

I'm still studying functions and I haven't studied this type of problem, however I though a bit about the problem and I thought that if I do the first derivative of f(x) in other words
$$f′(x) = 2\ln(e) x^{2x}$$

if we do $g'(x)= 10$ which is the gradient of the second function $g(x)$ and we find the value of x, that value of x is the value of x which is vertically furthest away from the other function.

I'm not sure if this method is correct, if anybody can help me it would be great!

this is the graph of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$

[image: 1]

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

You are right in the general direction of your approach. You did not mention whether you specifically want the place where $f > g$ or $g > f$, or it does not matter. I will assume it does not matter.

The distance between the functions would be given by
$$
d(x) = f(x) - g(x) = 2^{2x} - 10x - 2 = 4^x-10x-2.
$$
Recall that $d\left(a^x\right)/dx = a^x \ln(a)$, so its derivative would be
$$
d'(x) = 4^x \ln(4) - 10,
$$
so solving for the roots of the derivative you have
$$
\begin{split}
0 &= d'(x) = 4^x \ln (4) - 10 \\
4^x &= \frac{10}{\ln(4)} \\
x &= \frac{\ln(10) - \ln(\ln(4))}{\ln(4)} \approx 1.425
\end{split}
$$

Now you have to think what happens at that point and at the end points of the interval. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks! that was very useful!

Comment: @MatinGomez-Pablos glad to be of help.